# find the area of the region. interior of r = 8 cos θ

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

How exactly do I find (a) and (b) in terms of the boundaries for integration.
Also if you could provide a solution that would be very helpful in my understanding.

Comment: What do (a) and (b) mean here? The lower and upper bounds of the integral? What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, (a) and (b) represent the upper and lower bound. I mostly just need help with identifying what value they should be.

Comment: @Draconis look above

Comment: What does the graph look like? Are you required to use an integral?

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Polar_Integration.